# Bind Certificate to Port

Tags: networking, server, 16.04, ssl, mono

I am running a `.NET` application with `mono` on `Ubuntu 16.04`. The application is using `Grapevine` to run a small server that is set to listen for `HTTPS` connections on `8443`.

The server is listening on `localhost:8443` and `Nmap` shows that `8443` is open.

However when I browse to the `serverIp:8443/request` I am unable to connect, Chrome shows, `This site can’t be reached`.

I have tried the same application on `8080` using `HTTP` and it works fine, seems to be limited to when I use `HTTPS`.

I have the same setup on a Windows windows machine and had to bind an `ssl` certificate to `8443` in order for this to work.

I looked around and the only articles involve `Apache`, which I am not using.

Is there another way to go about this?

Comment: If your service is listening on localhost only you won't access it from outside on the server's external IP. You have to bind your app to your server's IP. All basically all interfaces/IPs.  That's assuming - of course - that your localhost above isn't only some kind of simplification in your scenario description. Other than that the problem may be also with some firewall, for example.

Comment: No simplification, is is set to use `localhost`. Would `0.0.0.0` make it listen to all? I'm away from that system right now so I can't try it as yet

Comment: Refer to your application manual - it will tell you how to bind it properly. But yes - in netstat or some other tools you should see 8443 listening on 0.0.0.0 then, if all interfaces are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue, as alluded to by Jacek, was that I was using `localhost`.

I changed the code as below and it worked fine in so far as external requests were reaching the application.

`Host = Configuration.Config.Get("grapevine-host", "localhost")`

To

`Host = Configuration.Config.Get("grapevine-host", "*")`